# Length of empty array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i'm trying to do one of the most basic things, and i am wondering what's wrong with my approach.

i have an object containing rooms

```
{ rooms: 
   { ijxeczyu: 
      { Id: 'ijxeczyu',
        teacherName: 'testteacher',
        teacherId: '/#Ikosyfr1NtDcpKbaAAAA',
        clients: [] } },
  getRooms: [Function],
  addRoom: [Function] }
```

now i want to render their info to a table in jade.
for that to work, i want to extract the important stuff and push it to an array

```
function makeArray(obj) {

  var roomArray = [];

  for (var room in obj) {
    roomArray.push({
      roomId  : room.Id,
      teacher : room.teacherName,
      clients : room.clients.length || 0
    })
  }
  return roomArray;
}
```

pretty easy.
**but** i can't get that empty clients array to work.
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
isn't that exactly what the `|| 0`part should catch?

why doesn't this work? how can i read the length of an array or `0` if there are no entries?

Comment: Presuming you mean that room.clients is undefined, then the `|| 0` is too late. Instead, you can do:
`(room.clients || []).length`

Answer (score 4):

`room.clients` is `undefined` which is why you get that error. The reason it's `undefined` is because `room` is a string.

A [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over the keys of an object. This means that `room === "ijxeczyu"`, assuming you're passing in your `rooms` object. To get access to the object, you'll have to access the object *at that key*.

```
for (var name in obj) {
  var room = obj[name];
  ...
}
```

Comment: aaaaahhhh ok. now it makes sense. so basically, a for..in loop is pretty much no advantage over a standard for loop?

Comment: @user3787706 The advantage is that you can use it to iterate over the keys of an object. A standard `for` loop is for iterating over arrays. `for (var key in obj)` vs. `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`. You could also get the keys using `Object.keys(obj)` then use a standard `for` loop over those.

Comment: Ecmascript 7 adds `for value of object`, which iterates over the values instead of the keys.